# Audio is muted after app regains focus on Android 12

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an app built with Unity. There seems to be an issue with audio on Android 12. When the app loses focus (minimized) and is brought back to focus again, the sound/audio no longer plays, almost as if it's been muted.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? And is there a fix?

I'm testing on a Samsung A22-5G.
Unity version is: 2020.3.35f1

Comment: Same problem here, got multiple reports from users about sound issue, all related to Android 12 devices. Investigating this now.

Answer (score 0):

Still investigating the problem, but here's a quick workaround (tested with Unity 2021.2.19f1).
Go to `Project Settings > Player > Other Settings`, enable "`Mute Other Audio Sources`".

Still working on a softer solution...

Currently can't check the issue with the newest Unity version.

**Update 1**

Seems like the issue is related to FMOD and should have been fixed in the newest Unity versions. https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-player-crashing-in-fmod-when-targetting-sdk-level-31